# How to extract the same Word multiple time from a String using Regular Expression withou knowing how often the Word occures in the String

Tags: regex

I have a Problem that could be solved using Regular Expresion. I have a String that contains some substring that all contains the Word "kago". It looks like this

> "ka_begin_dido_kon_ti | be_doit_**kago**_end_do | bin_begin_niko_end_se
>   | ho_begin_**kago**_log_lo |du_nonit_**kago**_si_ki"

Now I wrote aRegular Expresion that findes the first "kago"

```
.*(([a-zA-z]+_)+kago(_[a-zA-z]+)+ ).*
```

Output: be_begin_kago_end_do

The Problem is I can extract with this one only the First "kago" Word and not also the second or third (it can be up to 10 "kago" words in one String). How can i extract multiple times the "kago" word without knowing how often it repeats in the String?

I want to have as Output something like this:

> "be_doit_**kago**_end_do | ho_begin_**kago**_log_lo | du_nonit_**kago**_si_ki"

Comment: is `|` part of your String?

Comment: Try [`([a-zA-Z_]+)_kago_([a-zA-Z_]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rlCRyv/2). BTW, you might also split with ` | ` and then filter out those not containing `_kago_`. What is the programming language?

Comment: I use Tableau and the REGEXP_EXTRACT function

Comment: ([a-zA-Z_]+)_kago_([a-zA-Z_]+) Dont work it still takes just the first match

Comment: Yes "|" is a part of the string"

Comment: The problem is not the regex, Tableau has no function to return multiple matches. There is no way to present them, what do you expect your results to look like?

Comment: Read my Post again on the End it is writen how the output should look like

Comment: do you mean [`[^\|]*kago[^\|]*`](https://regex101.com/r/ZHiNsj/1/)

Comment: YCF_L
The Problem is not to match the SubString I want, I allready match it, but I wana match also the other SubStings in the same String so I get not only the first SubString that looks like this but also the other SubStrings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex with simple \w - Which accept any alphanumeric character

```
\w_kago_\w
```

Comment: The Problem is not to match the SubString I want, I allready match it, but I wana match also the other SubStings in the same String so I get not only the first SubString that looks like this but also the other SubStrings.